# MySql How to use DATE_SUB in Between clause

Tags: mysql

I am having problem while using DATE_SUB for DateTime fields.  I want to use query like this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    SellBySalesman 
WHERE 
    userid=37 and 
    sellingDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 17):

I am not sure what error you are getting, but this will not work.  The reason is that the arguments in your [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) clause are reversed.  [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) requires the first argument to be the min and the second to be the max.  [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) will subtract the interval from the date provided making it less than the current date.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    SellBySalesman 
WHERE 
    userid=37 and 
    sellingDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: Precise and logical. Thanks @Buggabill. This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your BETWEEN values are backwards.

You need to have the smaller value first: "BETWEEN 1 and 10" not "BETWEEN 10 and 1".

So, in your case, you want "BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and CURDATE()"

Answer (score 1):

You have to invert the order of between like this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    SellBySalesman 
WHERE 
    userid=37 and 
    sellingDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE();
```